# AWS amazon android firebase push notification

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, notifications

I have an issue with implementing Android AWS Amazon push notification using firebase, in Amazon sample, it shows you to add this line of code

[link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/mobile-sdk-android-modify.html)

```
AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getPinpointManager().getNotificationClient().registerGCMDeviceToken(refreshedToken);
```

But once you add it to the project `AWSMobileClient` class not initialized so I have added these SDK's

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.5'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.4.5'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-pinpoint:2.4.5'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.4.5'
```

But they didn't initialize, after searching I found that you have to add the sample so I added it
[Sample classes](https://github.com/tcsenzo/android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/senzo/amazonaws/mobile/AWSMobileClient.java)
but the classes didn't initialize.

So is there any straightforward example to Initializing this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps. You'll need to fill in:

- IDENTITY_POOL_ID
- APP_ID
- Adjust Regions.US_EAST_1 to whichever region you are using.

Code:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context,"IDENTITY_POOL_ID",Regions.US_EAST_1);

PinpointConfiguration config = new PinpointConfiguration(context, "APP_ID", Regions.US_EAST_1, cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider);

PinpointManager pinpointManager = new PinpointManager(config);

pinpointManager.getNotificationClient().registerGCMDeviceToken(refreshedToken);
```