# Push notification AWS firebase not working

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification

After I have Implemented this answer
[second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145194/aws-amazon-android-firebase-push-notification/45214627#45214627)

It shows the new devices registered in amazon correctly but i cant receving a push notification at the android devices

here is the code I have used to registration

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context,"IDENTITY_POOL_ID",Regions.US_EAST_1);

PinpointConfiguration config = new PinpointConfiguration(context, "APP_ID", Regions.US_EAST_1, cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider);

PinpointManager pinpointManager = new PinpointManager(config);

pinpointManager.getNotificationClient().registerGCMDeviceToken(refreshedToken);
```

and this for receiver

```
 <receiver
    android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.targeting.notification.PinpointNotificationReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.amazonaws.intent.fcm.NOTIFICATION_OPEN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

so how to solve this problem or is there anything which is missing

Answer (score 0):

i have checked the API key it was wrong and every thing working correctly now